# Two package versions for two dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, structuremap, nuget-package

In my project I have two dependencies having reference to two different versions of the same assembly (structuremap v2.6.4 vs v3.1.4.1), there is any way to resolve this properly with nugget ?

Comment: Do you need both versions for separate projects, or do you just want the same version across all project?

Comment: I need the two version for the same project, I reference in my project A, two dependencies B and C (which need structuremap but in different version)

Comment: Why do you require different versions?

Comment: @Steven In the past I've needed different versions of a dependencies because an SDK I was using only supported an out of date version of the required dependency, but I ~also~ needed functionality from the newer version.

Comment: Welcome in the DLL-hell. That's why [reusable libraries should not use any container at all](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/).

Comment: @Steven the pb is that the dependencies are both external (no one is my project)

Answer (score 1):

One way you can approach this issue is to use the NuGet Package `Costura.Fody` - which essentially bundles all .dlls of different versions for you to use in a project.

First step would be to install the package

After installing the package you'll see a `FodyWeavers.xml in your solution explorer.  This can be edited to include or exclude certain .dll's, but every time I have ever used it I just keep the default values which ends up being...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Weavers>
<Costura/>  
</Weavers>
```

What this enables you to do is place one of the .dll's into a `Libraries` folder in your solution (or elsewhere), and Costura.Fody will bundle all .dll's in your solution into one large dll (within the project that your XML was created).

Doing this you should be able to reference both versions - as I had to do this recently for a project to use two different versions of a .dll.

To verify that is has worked correctly you can view the size of the project's .dll before you add the NuGet package, and after and it should have grown in size to add in all of the other bundled .dll's.

I hope this helps!  Let me know if you have any questions!